# Twisted: Flask app not able to write logs through twisted

Tags: python, apache, flask, twisted, twisted.web

I'm trying to serve an existing flask app through twisted.  The same code works and logs are generated correctly if I run the app through apache. However, in twisted, the application runs fine but without the logs.

The Twisted's tac file looks like following. I've copied it mostly from [here](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.0.0/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html#serving-wsgi-applications).

File: **flask.tac**

```
from freshn import flipn # The flask app

# Create and start a thread pool,
wsgiThreadPool = ThreadPool()
wsgiThreadPool.start()

# ensuring that it will be stopped when the reactor shuts down
reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('after', 'shutdown', wsgiThreadPool.stop)

# Create the WSGI resource
wsgiAppAsResource = WSGIResource(reactor, wsgiThreadPool, flipn)

# Hooks for twistd
application = service.Application('Twisted.web.wsgi Hello World Example')
server = strports.service('tcp:8080', server.Site(wsgiAppAsResource))
server.setServiceParent(application)
```

The command I'm using to run is

```
twistd -ny flask.tac
```

Here is the code for initializing the logger in flask:

File: **init**.py

```
flipn = Flask(__name__)

current_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
log_file = os.path.join(current_dir,'threadflask.log')

file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(log_file, maxBytes=10000, backupCount=1)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
flipn.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
flipn.logger.info("Logging exceptions to %s" % log_file)
```

The log file gets created every time, but remains empty. Any pointers?

Comment: Permissions problem?

Comment: @KlausD. - Don't think so. As I've mentioned at the very end of question, the log file does get created. So if I rename 'threadflask.log' to say 'threadflask11.log', the new log file will be created. But it remains empty. Don't think its a buffering issue either.